# If a line starts with {condition}, insert variable after 187th character

Tags: text-processing

I have a .txt file with >10k lines. Some of the lines start with `1,POS,MGC=`or `1,NEG,MGC=`. For these lines, I want to insert a variable after the 187th character on the line while preserving the text after.

So far what I have is

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}
{if (substr($0,1,10)~"1,...,MGC=")
$187=$variable} inputfile > outputfile
```

which doesn't really work at all.

Comment: I *suspect* what you want is something like `awk -v x="$variable" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} /^1,...,MGC=/ {$187 = $187 x} {print}'`

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`:

```
sed "/^1,\(POS\|NEG\),MGC=/ s/./\0$variable/187" file
```

`.` matches any character, and the numerical flag `187` will cause `s/.../.../` to replace the 187th match instead.  Together, this means that the 187th character is replaced by itself followed by the value of `$variable`.

The leading `/pattern/` restricts this action to lines starting with "1,POS,MGC=" or "1,NEG,MGC=".

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
awk -vINSVAR="$variable" '/1,(POS|NEG),MGC/ {$0 = substr ($0, 1, 187) INSVAR substr ($0, 188)} 1' file
```

Comment: thanks @glenn jackman for correcting my sloppiness!

Answer (score 1):

Using perl:

```
perl -i.bak -spe 's/^(?=1,(POS|NEG),MGC=).{187}\K/$new/' -- -new="$text" file
```

Testing

```
line=$(seq 63 | paste -sd,)
lines=( "$line" "1,POS,MGC=$line" "1,NEG,MGC=$line" "1,foo,MGC=$line" )
printf "%s\n" "${lines[@]}" | perl -spe 's/^(?=1,(?:POS|NEG),MGC=).{187}\K/$new/' -- -new="HELLO!"
```

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63
1,POS,MGC=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,HELLO!63
1,NEG,MGC=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,HELLO!63
1,foo,MGC=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63
```